# Подскажите многофункциональную Java библиотеку для работы с картинками?

Tags: java, обработка-изображений

Чтобы снизить количество переключений между текстурами во время выполнения пытаюсь вставить в движок поддержку мегатекстур(атласа). Чтобы его сгенерировать пишу Win32 Java утилиту получающую на вход несколько файлов-картинок с содержанием текселей, дающую на выходе мегатекстуру плюс конфигурационный файл с мета информацией о ней для движка. Для того чтобы утилита работала нужно подключить к ней готовую Java библиотеку для программной работы с картинками(ковыряться самому в спецификациях форматов слишком долго).

Необходимый функционал:

1. Возможность отличить картинку с альфа каналом от картинки без альфа канала.
2. Возможность вставить одну картинку в другую и сохранить получившийся файл плюс применить пару простых фильтров(масштабирование, обрезка).
3. Поддержка tga, png, jpg, bmp форматов и конвертации между ними в разные стороны.

Наверняка нечто подобное уже существует, поэтому запрашиваю пруфлинк на сайт/документацию и.т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) + интерфейс на java к нему [jmagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html).

Может вытворять с изображениями просто чудесные вещи. Резать/клеить/накладывать эффекты/масштабировать с сглаживаниям. У jmagick есть только один недостаток - он немножко неаккуратно работает с памятью. Если кодировать картинки в течении суток - может скушать пару гигов памяти.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю завтра. Память не имеет значение, так как текстур не очень много и все эти операции нужно один раз только проделать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите также Marvin: http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html
А также: https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr